# How to resolve this issue in vs code a file is showing modify (M) symbol even after saving the changes & push it to the github

Tags: github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs1NW.png)

tried to push it multiple times in from vscode to github but its showing that same symbol (M)
And even tried to find about it in youtube but it was a waste of time like found nothing related to my problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.